# How to load page contents with webpack 4 similar to jquery $.load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

i'm facing a problem with `webpack 4` content load, how i used to do with `jquery`.

Here is what i'm trying to do with `webpack 4`

let say i have a page `setting.html`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="setting.css">
<div id="settingContent">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
<script src="setting.js"></script>
```

on click of **setting tab** i want to load this page into `index.html`, **#pageContent**

**index.html**

```
<div id="pageContent">

</div>
```

with jquery i used to do it as shown below.

```
$('setting_tab').on('click',function(){
    $('#pageContent').load('setting.html');
});
```

**below is my webpack config file looks like**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

    module.exports = {
        entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/js/index.js'],
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            filename: 'js/bundle.js'
        },
        devServer: {
            contentBase: './dist'
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                filename: 'index.html',
                template: './src/index.html'
            })
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    };
```

Comment: `webpack` isn't meant to do this